# Retrieve the values in an OptionSetValueCollection in C# Dataverse

Tags: c#, plugins, sdk, crm, dataverse

I am trying to retrieve the `OptionSetValueCollection` in a column of an entity.
The following line of code returns `null` despite the column having a value:

```
var valueCollection = record.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValueCollection>("my_attribute");
```

also

```
var valueCollection = (OptionSetValueCollection)record["my_attribute"];
```

yields the same result.

How can I get the `OptionSetValueCollection` in a column?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code retrieving the record. I guess attribute `my_attribute` was not specified...